# Optimization of Impressions across Property & category level for maximum clicks with constraints

Tags: r, optimization, analytics

I have dataset with 5 columns : Category, Property, Impressions, Clicks & CTR. Keeping the ctr constant at Category x property level, I want to redistribute impressions to give maximum clicks at a category x property level with 2 constraint:
1)Sum of impressions at a property level should be the same as in base table &
2)Sum of clicks at a category level should be the same as in base table

I am trying to write a code on R but getting an error which I'm not able to understand:

```
    library(lpSolve)
    df<-read.csv("data.csv")
    
    actual_property_impressions=df%>%group_by(Property)%>%summarise(prop_imp=sum(Impressions))
    actual_category_clicks=df%>%group_by(Category)%>%summarise(cat_clicks=sum(Clicks))
    
    # Defining the objective function
    
    objective <- function(x) {
      clicks <- x * df$CTR
      total_clicks <- sum(clicks)
      return(total_clicks)  
    }
    
    #Defining the constraint
    
    constraint <- function(x) {
      # Calculate the sum of impressions for each category
      constraint1 <- tapply(x, df$Property, sum) - sum(actual_category_clicks$cat_clicks)
      constraint2 <- tapply(x * df$CTR, df$Category, sum) - sum(actual_property_impressions$prop_imp)
    
      constraints <- c(constraint1, constraint2)
      return(constraints)
    }
    
    #initial guess
    
    i0 <- df$Impressions
    
    #Using Optim function
    
    result <- optim(
      par = i0,
      fn = objective,
      method = "L-BFGS-B",
      control = list(fnscale = -1),
      ui = NULL,
      ci = list(
        fun = constraint,
        type = c("==", "=="),
        rhs = c(0, 0)
      )
    )
    
    # Get the optimized impressions
    redistribution <- result$par
    
    }
```

On running this I'm getting the below error:

```
Error in fn(par, ...) : unused argument (constraints = list(function (x) 
{
    constraint1 <- tapply(x, df$Property, sum) - sum(actual_property_impressions$prop_imp)
    constraint2 <- tapply(x * df$CTR, df$Category, sum) - sum(actual_category_clicks$cat_clicks)
    constraints <- c(constraint1, constraint2)
    return(constraints)
}, Error in fn(par, ...) : 
  unused arguments (ui = NULL, ci = list(function (x) 
{
    prop_impressions <- tapply(x, df$Store_prop, sum)
    constraints <- c(sum(prop_impressions) - total_impressions_base, sum(x) - total_clicks_base)
    return(constraints)
 c("==", "=="), c(0, 0)))}
```

My queries are:

1. Is the approach correct?
2. Is the 'Optim' function the right one?
3. Why am I getting this error? I'm not to identify the mistake

Comment: From what I can see, you are adding arguments into `optim()` (`ui` and `ci` that are not recognized by the function.

Comment: Even if I use 'constrOptim' it is still giving me similar error